# Autoclicker that clicks left click and uses left click as the hot key

Tags: python, pyautogui

This seems really simple but, I realized the issue is that when pyautogui left clicks the key state is reset to up even though I may still be holding down left click.

```
import win32api
import pyautogui


state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) 
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.06
stop_key_state = win32api.GetKeyState(0x50) 

while True: 
a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) 
b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x50)

if b < 0:
    False

if a != state_left:  # Button state changed 
    state_left = a 
    if a < 0:
        while True:
            a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
            if a < 0:
                pyautogui.click()
                #print('Left Button Pressed') 
            else:
                False
    else: 
        print('Left Button Released')
```

Comment: I don't get it.  Are you trying to have both you and `pyautogui` manage the left mouse button?  How do you think that's going to work?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes sorry I wasn't very clear when I hold down left click I want pyautogui to click until I release the left mouse button and then it should stop

Comment: How do you think that'a going to work?  If you're already holding the left button down, what do you think `pyautogui` is going to do?  Hold it down harder?  There's only one cursor.  You are not thinking about this clearly.

Comment: @TimRoberts When I hold down left click I want pyautogui to repeatedly move left click up and down until I let go of left click

Comment: That's just not how the event system works.  All sources funnel into one state.  If pyautogui does a "left click up", then the system is going to see the left button as having been released.  Do you see?  You can't have left click be both DOWN and UP at the same time.